# Python defaultdict reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, defaultdict

Actually, I don't know how to explain this question in a proper title. Any edition is welcome.

Let's just see the example.

```
# python 2.7.x
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
d['a'] = 2
d['b'] = 1
res = [d]* 2
res[0]['a'] -= 1
print res[1]
# => defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'b': 1})
```

I was wondering why it affects the `res[1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `res` is a list of 2 elements *which are each the same object*: `d`.

Comment: Then how do I rewrite it to make it unique?

Comment: You need to instantiate several defaultdict: `res = [collections.defaultdict(int), collections.defaultdict(int)]` or even better: `res = [collections.defaultdict(int) for _ in range(2)]`

Comment: @cglacet But that is not what the OP's code intends to do. The OP's code intends to initialize a `defaultdict` with certain values and *then* make a list of several copies of the `defaultdict`. Your suggestion would result in a list of several empty `defaultdict` instead.

Comment: That's correct, in that case you'll need to use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html#module-copy) module.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the repeater operator `*`, which simply copies the reference to `d`, you can use a list comprehension with a copy of the `d` as the output in each iteration:

```
res = [d.copy() for _ in range(2)]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/0gnmkV

Answer (score 0):

Because they point to the same object. You can see this by running

```
print(id(res[0]))
print(id(res[1]))
```

if you don't want them to mimic each other you can do a copy of the dictionary.